# Topic deleted with an answer

Tags: discussion

Just now a second topic from a user whose alias i don't remember was deleted by, I suppose, moderator @Dmitry. His request had to do with a textbook exercise with possessive/reflexive pronouns.

The topic had an answer from myself.

Now, how about restoring the topic and simply putting it on hold until the OP meets the requirements for formulating questions?

I think deleting poorly articulated questions which nevertheless already have answers is unfair, disrespectful and inconsiderate towards the contributors who invested their time and effort in putting together answers only to be flushed down the drain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your disappointment, but please read this: 
[Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

> Generally speaking, answering questions that should get closed encourages bad behavior.

Comment: **1.** the OP could have been given longer time to improve his question; **2.** since this site is designed to provide helpful information, a meaningful answer to a poorly articulated question could still be valuable for other users currently and in the future, so it's more fair to let the community decide how much off-topic and abusive a question is, if the participants ignore it completely or give answers just as left field with no useful information then it indeed may deserve to be deleted; **3.** can this particular topic be restored or can at least my response be fetched and handed to me?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка **1.** The time and the feedback have been given, but the OP decided to duplicate his post. **2.** Have you read my answer? **3.** Are you able to use [tools](https://russian.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days)?

Comment: yes, i can access the tools, thank for the link